# Magento add custom amount in checkout cart page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, cart, observers

I wanted to add a custom Fee to the cart total like we have discount ...
But it should be added only when a condition satisfies , like if checkbox clicked from frontend by customer .

Have referred : http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total

But it adds by default .

Please give any hint .

Comment: Any Solution please?

Answer (score 0):

The logic whether to apply or not to apply the fee is located in Excellence_Fee_Model_Fee::canApply(). This is a static function that returns true by default. Add your custom logic there... when it returns true it will add the fee.

Comment: Yeah but how can the customer control the condition that addition/revert from cart part .

Comment: For instance: when the checkbox is clicked add a value in the customer session and check on that in the canApply() method.